# How to make a primary key which is a combination of both a foreign key and a column

Tags: sqlite

I am creating two tables T1 and T2 in my database.

T1 with columns A, B, and C, where A is the primary key.

T2 with columns A, D, E, and F, where A is the foreign key, and the combination of (A, D) the primary key.

Is it possible to create this primary key with a combination of a foreign key and another column? If possible, then what is the sql statement I write to create the table T2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
create table t2 (
    a integer not null references t1(a),
    d integer not null,
    e integer,
    f integer,
    primary key (a,d) 
)
```

Comment: I used this, but tell me one thing, when I am inserting the values to these tables, do I insert 'A' value in both the tables or is it just enough to insert in T1.

Comment: Just T1 is enough, but just T2 is not enough (because the referenced row in the master table is missing). Not sure if SQLite enforces this, though.